# Is keyframed animation in Unity C2 continuous?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering if a Unity animations using [keyframes](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Keyframe.html) where inTangent = -outTangent is automatically C2 continuous?